# combobox в tool\cool\action box

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

есть такая прога keepass (у др. тоже ранее видел, просто как пример). там сверху куда-то (из того что знаю, возможно - cool\tool\action bar) запихнута разновидность (может и нет) combobox. с функцией поиска по БД. сама функция и др. мало интересны. подскажите, как это реализовать на дельфи (combobox в строку кнопок под меню)?
в описании на вики к KP сказано, что написана на c#. сторонние компоненты скорее всего эту фичу имеют, а на стд. как повторить?

желательно пример. d10 starter. спасибо.

скрины (с "или" просмотра, не знаю сколько проживут потому 3 делаю)
[image: keepass combo in tool bar]

http://s019.radikal.ru/i643/1704/68/c6466c838eec.png

http://uploads.ru/cnaVD.png

http://savepic.ru/13608389.png

Comment: а что, нельзя добавить комбобокс в тулбар?

Comment: спасибо за ответ. ммм... а как это сделать? просто туда перетянуть можно, но это же не всамомделишный получится. + версия д - стартер - может там чего нет? + сейчас маинменю и тулбал кнопок реализованы через актионманаджер.

Comment: не понял вашего предложения. что не так если просто перетянуть комбобокс на тулбар?

Comment: он там не закрепляется и потомком тб не является. если тб скрыть кб остается и все кривеет. двигать тб нельзя вместе с кб.

Comment: я может не все прочитал про это, но пока не вижу способов, может просто мало знаний? покажите где почитать, если не сложно (перетаскивание combobox на actiontoolbar).

Comment: ну возьмите coolbar тогда, туда то уж можно контролы (`TWinControl`)перетаскивать точно. я бы проверил, но у меня не установлена среда.

Comment: да, это работает, спасибо. но хочется решения для ActionMainMenuBar и бара ActionToolBar через ActionManager. ++ если вы коммент выше оформите как ответ через неделю я его приму, без проблем. но может еще решения будут.

Comment: ++ примерно год назад читал _убедительную_ статью (не помню где), для дельфи, что вот теперь лучше избегать mainmenu, toolbar и все делать только через actionmanager. с одной стороны да, удобно, если разобраться, с другой.. если не нужно то зачем... видимо в keepass это не одобряют.

Comment: каждому компоненту свое применение. в ActionBar вы не добавите комбобокс. Там в принципе подход другой с использованием настройки действий вызываемых из разных мест, тулбара и меню и т.п. (честно сказать когда активно использовал delphi, то этим компонентом дел не имел особо) Он в целом может быть хорош, но для соответствующих целей. Никто не отменял использование других компонентов построения тулбаров. Что наверное не следует использовать то это вкладку компонентов win 3.1, если она до сих по там жива, а остальное пользуйте, для этого оно там и находится в вашем распоряжении.

Comment: 2 terran - вам отписывал, чтобы "14 апр в 21:16 " как ответ защитать, но блин, это не то, тот не то, 40 мин нет между отв., основное - благодарен. если е возможность защитайте за ответ. ибо я не понимаю как. еще раз спасиб.